# Matlab: Calculate with same amount on every date and adjust when date changes (for-loop)

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, for-loop, dependencies

I’ve got three column vectors (300x1) **Date, VariousA, Amount** and I wanna perform a calculation for each row of my column vectors depending on the datetime-vector (Date).
If the date does not change, the amount in the calculation should not change either. If the date changes, I want to sum up all the results of the calculations of the previous date and add the sum to the amount of the previous date.

The following example is based on the table below:

First, the Amount-Vector only contains a value in the first row (**100**). The calculation delivers **60**. Since the date in the next row stays the same, the amount remains as well - the calculation delivers **30**.
Since the date in **row 3** changes, I now want to adjust my amount. The sum of the results on the previous date is **90** which should be added to the amount of the previous date. The new amount in **row 3** is therefor **190** and the calculation delivers **85.5** which need to be added to **190** in the next row because the date in row 4 changes again, and so on…

I hope it has become clear. Is there anybody able to help?

MANY THANKS IN ADVANCE!

```
| Date          | VariousA  | Amount    | Result    | HelpColumn    |
|-------------  |---------- |--------   |--------   |-------------- |
| 28-Jul-2001   | 0.6       | 100       | 60        | 100*0.6       |
| 28-Jul-2001   | 0.3       | 100       | 30        | 100*0.3       |
| 29-Jul-2001   | 0.45      | 190       | 85.5      | 190*0.45      |
| 04-Aug-2001   | -0.7      | 275.5     | -192.5    | 275.5*(-0.7)  |
| 04-Aug-2001   | 0.1       | 275.5     | 27.55     | 275.5*0.1     |
| 05-Aug-2001   | 0.4       | 110.55    | 44.22     | 110.55*0.4    |
```

EDIT: I've figured out this Code but it does not work at all:

```
if     i>1 & Date(i)>Date(i-1) 
            Amount(i) = sum(Result(find(Date==Date(i-1)))) + Amount(i-1);
elseif i>1 & Date(i)==Date(i-1)    
            Amount(i) = Amount(i-1);
end  
Result(i)=VariousA(i)*Amount(i);
```

Comment: there is no code (which seems you intended to post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure, but is this what you are looking for?

```
DateString = {'07/28/2001';'07/28/2001';'07/29/2001';'08/04/2001';'08/04/2001';'08/05/2001'};
formatIn = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
Date=datevec(DateString,formatIn);
VariousA=[0.6;0.3;0.45;-0.7;0.1;0.4];
Amount=[100;0;0;0;0;0];
Result=zeros(length(VariousA),1);

k=1;

for i=1:1:length(VariousA)
    if i>1
        Amount(i)=Amount(i-1);

        if sum(Date(i,:)>Date(i-1,:))>0
            for j=1:1:k
                Amount(i)=Amount(i)+Result(i-j);
            end
            k=1;
        else
            k=k+1;
        end
    end
    Result(i)=VariousA(i)*Amount(i);

end
```

Comment: I was able to implement my code, there was only a bug but it seems that your code works as well. Thank you